# Can I use de-reference just once to get the value in 2-d array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know sometimes `matrix[x][y]`(x,y are both given)can be substituted by `*(*(matrix+x)+y)`. But can we use dereference just once to get a specially appointed (such as `matrix[2][3]`) value?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int matrix[3][4]={
        {1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12}};
    printf("%d\n",matrix[2][3]);
    printf("%d",*(matrix+2*4+3));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12
6422400
```

Comment: Your question really isn't clear.  It would help if you posted code that demonstrates exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Probably `printf("%d",*((int*)matrix+2*4+3));` (haven't checked it, though, and not sure about UB)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a dynamic array - no, because the data presented in different part of your memory. In case if your data goes byte by byte - yes - you can get it by

`*(matrix + 2*y + 3) == matrix[2][3]`

Comment: Note that this might accomplish nothing but reduced readability as you are basically doing what the compiler is doing anyway.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev, ofcourse, it is just a way to represent the idea of ​​n dimensional array in the memory (1 dimensional array). There are not many practical uses of this idea

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev When I want to use malloc to allocate memory to 2-d array or a pointer to pointer, there will be some wrongs because (void*) can't be changed (type  **), so I think maybe (void *) can be changed (type *) implicitly.

Comment: If `matrix` is a two dimensional array of `int`, such as `int matrix[3][4]`, then `*(matrix + 2*y + 3)` is a pointer to an array of `int`. In this case, with `y` = 4, it attempts to point 11 arrays beyond the start of `matrix`, which contains only 3 arrays, so it is invalid pointer arithmetic.